# Dell Studio XPS 16 Runs Hot

Tags: intel-core-i7, dell-xps

Specs:

- 1920x1080
- i7 1.6 GHz quad core
- 6GB RAM
- 1GB ATI Radeon HD 6570M/5700 Series
- 500GB 7200rpm Hard Drive

Love this laptop for many reasons, but it constantly runs hot (CPU is low 70s with basic tasks and often 80+ is not uncommon) and I'm finding it too much to deal with. The laptop feels very hot (almost too hot for a lap) and often gets so hot that the OS slows down or freezes altogether.

I've tried cleaning it out and even replacing the thermal paste. I often use an external cooler, but it only helps 3-5 degrees and it's a pain to have to use. I've come to the conclusion that it just runs hot.

I have two questions:

1. What is to blame? The i7 processor, the gfx card, or is it just that this laptop has poor cooling?
2. Does the Dell XPS 15 run cooler? I'm looking at replacing my current laptop, but I don't want to run into the same problem.

Comment: Does it usually sit on a fan?

Comment: @AlexYan maybe half the time.

Comment: Just for curiosity have you use it for games?

Comment: As I've read some blogs and reviews about this laptop most user has this problem. [Dell studio XPS](http://www.dexternights.com/2009/05/20/dell-studio-xps-16-review-a-super-hot-laptop/) & [Dell studio XPS review](http://reviews.cnet.com/laptops/dell-studio-xps-16/4852-3121_7-33490499.html).

Comment: @avirk Every now and then I play Civilization 5 - that's it. I'm well aware others have the issue. I mostly just want to find out what the culprit is so I can avoid it in another machine.

Comment: Most hot running laptops are due to poor design, the only way to avoid it is to buy a laptop 6 months after its initial debut release and read the owner reviews that have accumulated on the net.

Comment: I agree with @Moab. And I don't think that there is any solution for this even on the dell support yet.

Comment: Ok, so consensus is leaning toward it just being this model and not any of the hardware components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion is that this particular laptop is just terrible at cooling. I'm using a Studio XPS 15 and VERY happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

Well i have the same thing.  Bought it for my wife ~3 years ago.  I noticed when we FIRST got it that it ran hot, i told her we should send it back, but she had a nice shiny new laptop and didnt want to.

Long story short, i will NEVER buy another dell again.  This is the second lemon i have gotten from them (laptop and desktop) - the last 2 pc's i bought from them.

DO NOT BUY A DELL LAPTOP, they overheat - just google and you will see.  I dont think people undertand that when it runs hot, your performance suffer greatly, the life is reduced, its annoying with the fan always running, etc.

To answer your question, the DESIGN of the laptop is to blame.  It does not allow for proper cooling therefore it overheats!  I would not change to another DELL, look at some other brands and research before you buy.  If you were to research this before you bought the dell laptop, im sure you would not have purchased it.

Comment: Wouldn't say I wouldn't buy another Dell laptop. I bought a Studio XPS 15 and am VERY happy with it. It handles heat like a champ.

Comment: Thanks dtbarne - that gives me hope as i used to buy dells all the time.  I wish i could try before buy so it would be easy to see if it was flawed pretty quickly